# assert p.name("String").equals("Child String")

Tags: java

```
interface Parent {
  public String name(Object b);
}

class Child implements Parent {
  public String name(Object b) {
    return [???];
  }
  public String name(String b) {
    return "Child " + [???];
  }
}

public class Exercise {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent p = new Child();
    assert p.name("String").equals("Child String");
  }
}
```

Is there any way to replace the '[???]' within the code above so that the assert returns trues?

Comment: Why does `public String name(Object b)` even exist?

Comment: First you should determine which `name` method gets called by the `main` method. Then you have to make sure that this method returns "Child String".

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the method `name` is overloaded. But you could use `instanceof` to check for the type of the parameter `b`.

```
public String name(Object b) {
  if (b instanceof String) {
    return name((String) b);
  }
  return "something else";
}

public String name(String b) {
  return "Child " + b;
}
```